# How Should Titles Be Capitalized?

Tags: discussion, titles

Many (most?) titles on Stack Exchange are phrased as questions, rather than traditionally.

> What Does X Mean?
>
> Meaning of X

When I do this, I make sure to use Title Caps.  It's still a title, after all - just phrased as a question.

Several times now - on other SE sites, as well - [my questions have been edited](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44176/how-do-i-refer-to-a-word) to "fix" this.  I usually just do a rollback, but I want to make sure it's okay.

Is there a site convention for title capitalization?  Should there be?

Comment: So... what I see up there now: **How Should Titles Be Capitalized?** is just a parody?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's really more of a *question summary* than a title. Sure, it appears in big bold letters above the question... But it also appears with others, packed in like sardines, in the list on the front page and the questions pages. And in the latter context, "title case" really doesn't make much sense.

FWIW, this has [come up on MSO before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98066/capitalizing-titles), and the overwhelming preference is for sentence case.

Answer (score 6):

I re-corrected it. All titles are written low case, except for the first letter and proper nouns, of course.

I'm not sure there is a rule specifically for the SE sites, but all titles are written like this, so I'd say that a rule of thumb would be to stick with the norm.

Answer (score 5):

I vote for "**Sentence case like this**" instead of "**Title Case Like This**", purely because it's the most readable.